# Change text options in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, select

I generated this form with a wordpress plugin and i can't put spaces on text. I want change text of options like this: UnaEstrella -> Una Estrella ... (not value text)

```
<select id="topics" class="taxonomies-filter-widget-input" name="topics">
    <option value="0">Todas</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="unaestrella">UnaEstrella</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="dosestrellas">DosEstrellas</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="tresestrellas">TresEstrellas</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="cuatroestrellas">CuatroEstrellas</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="cincoestrellas">CincoEstrellas</option>
</select>
```

Is possible change too with images?

Comment: Did you even try before posting ?

Comment: It's a wordpress plugin and i can't put spaces before posting

Comment: Where's that data coming from"?

Comment: first, I declare new taxonomy named "Topics", and later, i post that value from GF form (Gravity Forms). you can see it here:

http://www.buscatuspa.com/prueba-spa-guillen/ (in sidebar, second input named "Estrellas"

Comment: Where the `values` are coming from ? Do you want to convert `camelCase` to `camel_Case`, programmatically ?

Comment: i dont want "_" it's easy before posting, i want space " " or simply change the names. The values are value taxonomy on each post. But i can't change that value one by one

Comment: Ok, i supose thats not possible or something, but the second? Change values for images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
function camelToSpc(str) {
    return str.replace(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
}

$(function(){
    $('select#topics option').each(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(camelToSpc(txt));
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tHQW5/1/)

**Update :**

Make sure `jQuery` is added and replace `$` with `jQuery` or try

```
(function($) {
    $('select#topics option').each(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(camelToSpc(txt));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tHQW5/2/)

Comment: i put this code in .js loaded in sidebar (strx-magic-floating-sidebar-maker.js) but don't work! you know why, please? It's possible put this code in functions.php?

Comment: You should put this code in a `js` file or in `<head></head>` within `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: mmm i will try! If i can't do it, ask you again xD

Comment: Also, check [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: ok, thanks, i'm looking that, but i put the code in header and don't work. wou can see it in source code here http://www.buscatuspa.com/busca-tu-spa/

Comment: problem solved! I use wp_enqueue_script for add changetext.js and with the new code works fine! Really really thanks! I want ask for change thats values for images, must i put new ask?